# React-Redux connected component not passing updated props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Child components (MapLeftNav, Map) are not rerendering when application state is changed. It has a parent component (MapView) and several siblings.

Assumptions:

1) App state is changing and being tracked by Redux

- The action is showing up in Redux Dev tools, with updated fields;
- I'm logging the vehiclesState in the parent component (MapView), they are changing;

2) My reducer is not just mutating state ([gist here](https://gist.github.com/thomasgwatson/51e5a502c00967361da75f4e434de533))

-Redux dev tools and Parent (`connect`ed compoent) are happily picking up the changes

```
case NEW_MESSAGES:
  return reduceVehicleMessagesToVehicles(state, action.payload)
```

and then that function returns:

```
return {
  vehicles: updatedVehicles,
  traces: updatedTraces,
  vehicleMessagesLoading: messagesLoading,
}
```

3) The parent component ([MapView, gist here](https://gist.github.com/thomasgwatson/8663ffe394af54adf9b312255e3bdd58)) is receiving the new props but not the child MapLeftNav

- I console.log the props and they change in the Parent component
- I write a fake `componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps)
  {console.log(nextProps)}` and that function is NEVER fired by the
  child MapLeftNav component.

  ```
   <MapLeftNav
    mapState={mainMap}
    push={push}
    vehicles={vehiclesState.vehicles}
    updateCounter={vehiclesState.updateCounter}
   />
  ```

4) MapLeftNav component, as requested:
https://gist.github.com/thomasgwatson/36d8f6dbd64b0f6425b4beef56075acd

Using React, Redux, React-Redux bindings, react-redux dev tools, material UI and more. I've used React for about 18 months and Redux for two.

When I directly `connect` redux to the child components, everything works fine. When I just pass them to the parent component and try to pass application state down as props, the child components don't seem to register changes in state.

As I understand it, I should not have to `connect` all my components to be able to use the application state held in the redux store! Any tips on what the likely source of problems is?

Comment: You show ``MapLeftSideBar`` but also mention ``MapLeftNav``, I'm assuming that is a typo. Can you include the skeleton of your ``MapLeftNav`` component?

Comment: How are you `connect`ing the data to `MapLeftNav`? Could you paste the connection logic as well.

Comment: @bebraw I've added a link in the main post to the gist of the Parent component, which is at https://gist.github.com/thomasgwatson/8663ffe394af54adf9b312255e3bdd58
The `connect` is all happening at the Parent component level

Comment: @Underwater_developer Ok. This probably won't solve your problem, but you can consider moving `connect` lower in hierarchy (separate for both). At least then you can log the behavior easier per component. Maybe that will reveal something interesting. It's a good step perf-wise too.

Comment: @bebraw Yeah, I was dreaming of having a strong division between smart  `connect`ed components and dumb rendering ones.... but if connecting at the child component works, I might have to just use that as a work-around and move on. I'll try that.

Comment: @bebraw the direct `connect` works. Just feels unnecessary. I can't invest more time in this right now but still feel like its unresolved :(

Comment: @Underwater_developer looks like you are connecting the component correctly. Could it be something to do with shallow comparison? Try adding a ``random_number`` key to your ``mapStateToProps`` function and pass the random number value into the child component.